# Can a use case have several <<include>> cases?

Tags: uml, use-case

For example, if I have a use case called "Withdraw Cash" that ((includes>> to the use case "Verify Account," can "Withdraw Cash" also ((include>> to another use case called "Verify Balance?" Or can a use case ((include>> to only one use case? Any help would be very much appreciated.

"Withdraw Cash" ------include--> "Verify Account"

```
 |
 |---include---> "Verify Balance"
```

*Note: Sorry I have to simulate the <> with (>

Comment: **Yes**, see also http://www.uml-diagrams.org/use-case-include.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Also make sure that the included UC should always be part of the UC including it.

Answer (score -1):

To expand a little bit on answers given, you can have as many includes as you want.  As hzjw mentions, includes must *always* be part of the use case; whether it is included or not is not optional.  So your two examples are good ones.

Extends are optional.  The arrow goes from the extending use case to the use case being extended, which is sort of the backwards of includes.  An example of an extend in your case might be a Transfer Cash use case that could extend Verify Balance, which in the event that the balance were insufficient for the transaction would attempt to cover it from another account (charging an exorbitant fee as well, of course).

You can also have as many extends as you want.